# Is there a way to exclusively manage multiple ssh keys with differing per-key options using ansible?

Tags: ansible, ssh, key-management

Ansible provides a [ansible.builtin.authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html) module which provides a lot of functionality:

- You can set `exclusive: true` to delete all other keys.
- You can set `key_options: ...`.
- You can list multiple keys in `key` by separating them with new lines.

Is there a way to combine all of the above?

The naive approach results in the `key_options` to be applied to all keys rather than having key options per key.

Is this a case of generating `authorized_keys` using `ansible.builtin.file` given the exclusiveness?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use multiple authorized keys files, authorized_keys2 [is deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/116177/whats-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-authorized-keys2) but there's no reason you can't use it and you can specify multiple authorized keys files in sshd config

> ```
> AuthorizedKeysFile
>
>      Specifies the file that contains the public keys used for
>      user authentication.  The format is described in the
>      AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section of sshd(8).  Arguments
>      to AuthorizedKeysFile accept the tokens described in the
>      TOKENS section.  After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is
>      taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's
>      home directory.  Multiple files may be listed, separated by
>      whitespace.  Alternately this option may be set to none to
>      skip checking for user keys in files.  The default is
>      ".ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2".
> ```

this might not be the optimal solution to your problem, but I think you're going to have to hack on ansible yourself to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `#ansible` IRC channel noted that key options can be included in the multiline `key` field. When doing so, `key_options` can be left unset and things work.

Having to construct this multiline `key` field including options is pretty close to generating content for `ansible.builtin.file`. A minor benefit of doing this is that `ansible.builtin.authorized_key` actually parses the content and errors out when it does not parse before deploying it.